# How to run a simple ms sql query to test output

Tags: ms-access, vba

Suppose I want to write a ms sql code and I want to test what my sql command give output to test before I use it in the project or form. Suppose I want to see the result of the query

```
CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employee")(0)
```

To test vba code we have Immediate UI which can be accessed using Ctrl+g. I want something similar so that I can run the above query and can check what output I get. This is just test purpose. So I want something quick and easy. I don't want to create a query for this.

Comment: that code looks familiar ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Open the query GUI, switch to SQL view, and paste in your SQL string:

```
SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employee
```

Run the query and study the output.

Comment: How to open query GUI?

Comment: Go to create query, close the popup listing tables/queries, go to select view, select SQL.

Comment: Gustav, thought @user1670773 specifically mention `So I want something quick and easy. I don't want to create a query for this.` How does this meet the requirement?

Comment: It includes debugging. Of course, for statements like the actual that hardly can fail, it may not be that important.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to create a Query in the Query window, but use VBA/Immediate window to display the result. Use `CurrentDB.OpenRecordset` as you have, but also use the `Fields` method of the Object. So try this in the Immediate window.

```
? CurrentDB.OpenRecordSet("SELECT Max(AgentID) As MaxVal FROM Agents").Fields(0)
  200
```

Hope this helps!